# SPARK java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No Route to Host

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark

Good day,

I am trying to run the scala example for spark provided at the following link:

https://www.tutorialkart.com/apache-spark/scala-spark-shell-example/

I launch spark-shell using the following command (I added the port number since ports 4040-4045 were already in use)

```
spark-shell --master local[4] --conf spark.ui.port=4046
```

Once within spark, I try to enter the three lines provided, but on the second line, it gives the "No Route to Host" complaint:

```
scala> ^C^C[twagenhals@login-1 downloads]$ spark-shell --master local --conf spark.ui.port=4047
Setting default log level to "WARN".
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).
Spark context Web UI available at http://login-1:4047
Spark context available as 'sc' (master = local, app id = local-1554323767110).
Spark session available as 'spark'.
Welcome to
      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /___/ .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 2.4.0
      /_/

Using Scala version 2.11.12 (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_171)
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> var map = sc.textFile("wordcount_input.txt").flatMap(line => line.split(" ")).map(word => (word,1));
map: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, Int)] = MapPartitionsRDD[3] at map at <console>:24

scala> var counts = map.reduceByKey(_ + _);
java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No Route to Host from  login-1/10.2.0.2 to localhost:9000 failed on socket timeout exception: java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No route to host; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/NoRouteToHost
  at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
  at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.wrapWithMessage(NetUtils.java:792)
  at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.wrapException(NetUtils.java:758)
  at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1479)
  at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1412)
  at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:229)
  at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy23.getFileInfo(Unknown Source)
  at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.getFileInfo(ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.java:771)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
  at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:191)
  at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:102)
  at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy24.getFileInfo(Unknown Source)
  at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.getFileInfo(DFSClient.java:2108)
  at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$22.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1305)
  at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$22.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1301)
  at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystemLinkResolver.resolve(FileSystemLinkResolver.java:81)
  at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.getFileStatus(DistributedFileSystem.java:1317)
  at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Globber.getFileStatus(Globber.java:57)
  at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Globber.glob(Globber.java:252)
  at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.globStatus(FileSystem.java:1676)
  at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.singleThreadedListStatus(FileInputFormat.java:259)
  at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.listStatus(FileInputFormat.java:229)
  at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.getSplits(FileInputFormat.java:315)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD.getPartitions(HadoopRDD.scala:204)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:253)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:251)
  at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:251)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:49)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:253)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:251)
  at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:251)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:49)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:253)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:251)
  at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:251)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:49)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:253)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:251)
  at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:251)
  at org.apache.spark.Partitioner$$anonfun$4.apply(Partitioner.scala:78)
  at org.apache.spark.Partitioner$$anonfun$4.apply(Partitioner.scala:78)
  at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
  at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
  at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392)
  at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:234)
  at scala.collection.immutable.List.map(List.scala:296)
  at org.apache.spark.Partitioner$.defaultPartitioner(Partitioner.scala:78)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$reduceByKey$3.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:326)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$reduceByKey$3.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:326)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:363)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions.reduceByKey(PairRDDFunctions.scala:325)
  ... 49 elided
Caused by: java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No route to host
  at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
  at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:717)
  at org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketIOWithTimeout.connect(SocketIOWithTimeout.java:206)
  at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.connect(NetUtils.java:531)
  at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.connect(NetUtils.java:495)
  at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupConnection(Client.java:614)
  at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupIOstreams(Client.java:712)
  at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.access$2900(Client.java:375)
  at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.getConnection(Client.java:1528)
  at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1451)
  ... 105 more
```

I am unsure why this issue is occuring though and searching on the internet didn't give a clear reason. I tried not including --master, but the default value is still local[*], so the results are similar. I don't know what other options I can type here to try to get this to work. Is there some kind of attribute file I need to add so that some kind of relation is known before starting spark? I've seen this issue before within hadoop and it was related to configuring some .xml files, so that's the only other thing that comes to mind, but I don't know the relationship between each program and configuration files. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

EDIT: It appears part of the issue lies within my core-site.xml file within hadoop. When I have it set to the following configuration, it fails:

```
[twagenhals@login-1 scripts]$ cat $HADOOP_HOME/etc/hadoop/core-site.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>
<!--
Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
You may obtain a copy of the License at
http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
limitations under the License. See accompanying LICENSE file.
-->
<!-- Put site-specific property overrides in this file. -->
<configuration>
<property>
<name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name>
<value>/state/partition1/hadoop-twagenhals</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>fs.default.name</name>
<value>hdfs://localhost:9000</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

Removing all properties allows Spark to run, although I don't really know why.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>
<!--
Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
You may obtain a copy of the License at
http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
limitations under the License. See accompanying LICENSE file.
-->
<!-- Put site-specific property overrides in this file. -->
<configuration>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Few checks - Make sure you are there are no other hadoop services configured on your machine which is running besides spark. Usually if you have hdfs-site.xml pointing different servers where spark is running and that server has connectivity issues, then it could be the culprit. Also check your /etc/hosts file

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I actually just figured out the issue, although I don't necessarily know the underlying cause. The issue was actually my core-site.xml file, where I had configured hadoop to run in pseudo-distributed mode. For some reason, spark did not like this configuration and this error occurred. Clearing out core-site.xml so that hadoop runs in standalone mode allows spark to now run. I'm assuming the underlying issue has something to do with my yarn configuration not working correctly. I supposed I should work on figuring out that issue instead of running in standalone mode.